# PHP "Fatal Error: Class not found" when trying to instantiate class that extends a class from another file. Wordpress, but not specific to

Tags: php, wordpress

This question is particular to wordpress, but I don't believe it is a wordpress specific question.  I am getting a class not found error when I try to create a new object of type "sample_widget".  The code is below:

```
    global $wpdb;

    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../wp-load.php'); // Instantiate all the wordpress stuff, we are three subfolders removed from the /wp folder.

    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../wp-includes/script-loader.php'); // Instantiate all the wordpress stuff, we are three subfolders removed from the /wp folder.
    class sample_widget extends WP_Widget {

     public $widgetName = "sample_widget";

     public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
          $this->widgetName, // Base ID
          __('sample_widget', 'wpb_widget_domain'), // Name
          array( 'description' => __('sample_widget', 'wpb_widget_domain'), ) // Args

        );
      } // end of constructor

      public function whoami() {
        echo "This widget is called:" . $this->widgetName;
      }
      public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        echo "Widget stuff.";
      } // end of widget function

      public function form( $instance ) {
            echo "Form stuff.";
      }

      public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        return $instance;
      }
    } // end of class.

    add_action( 'widgets_init', function() {
         register_widget( 'sample_widget' );
    });


    function test_widget() {
        $obj = new sample_widget();
        echo "Who am I? " . $obj->whoami();
    }
```

Results in this: Fatal error: Class 'sample_widget' not found in /*my file*

I have created another base class, and derived from it, in the same file with no problems.  Other class instantiation works fine.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Also:

```
    $obj = new WP_Widget();
```

works fine.

Comment: Have you `include`d the file? These don't automagically load.

Comment: In which tag u r embedding php code? <? ?> or <?php ?> ?

Comment: Edited the original question to reflect answers to kinghfb and user2486495

Comment: I asked you about tags?

Comment: Apologies: It is all within <?php ?>

Answer (score 0):

to use an external file inside wordpress you should add this on the top:

```
<?php define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); require('../../../wp-load.php'); ?>
```